# canvas context getImageData() function won't execute, probably because it's executed before the image is loaded

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, getimagedata

what I'm trying to do is draw an image to an  html canvas using only javascript, and by using the getImageData() function, I'm trying to get the image's bits and then manipulate them in multiple ways.

however, because i'm loading the image using javascript, my suspicion is that the image can't load in time before the call to getImageData(), so the program just stops working when that call is made, as you can see the _log(3) statement isn't being called.

this happens even though I've called getImageData() function inside the images onload() event.

i've already seen a few suggestions in some other stackoverflow threads regarding this issue, but none of them seem to work for me.

any help in the right direction would be really appreciated.

here's the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/houqdfx9/2/

this is the html:

```
<p id="log"></p>
```

this is the javascript:

```
function _log(string){
    document.getElementById("log").innerHTML += string; 
}

function _createCanvas(){
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.setAttribute("id", "canvas");
  document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  return canvas;
}

function _drawAndProcessImage(img, ctx){
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    _log(img.width + " " + img.height + " ");
    var img_data = ctx.getImageData(0,0,img.width,img.height);
    _log(3);

    /* DO THINGS WITH THE IMG_DATA HERE */
}

function setCanvasAndLoadImage(url, canvas, callback) {
   var img = new Image;
   var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); 
   img.onload = function(){callback(img, ctx);};
   img.src = url;
   canvas.width = img.naturalWidth;
   canvas.height = img.naturalHeight;
};

var canvas = _createCanvas();

setCanvasAndLoadImage("https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2014/02/01/17/30/apple-256267_960_720.jpg", canvas, _drawAndProcessImage);
```

Comment: i wrote an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please try this.** This works. But, there is a cross domain violation because of the different domains. You would need to proxy this through a server maybe. [See](https://blog.codepen.io/2013/10/08/cross-domain-images-tainted-canvas/) this for a solution.

```js
function _log(string){
    document.getElementById("log").innerHTML += string; 
}

function _createCanvas(){
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.setAttribute("id", "canvas");
  document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  return canvas;
}

function _drawAndProcessImage(img, ctx){
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    _log(img.width + " " + img.height + " ");
    var img_data = ctx.getImageData(0,0,img.width,img.height);
    _log(3);

    /* DO THINGS WITH THE IMG_DATA HERE */
}

function setCanvasAndLoadImage(url, canvas, callback) {
   var img = new Image;
   var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); 
   img.onload = function() {
     canvas.width = img.naturalWidth;
     canvas.height = img.naturalHeight;

     callback(img, ctx);
   };
   img.src = url;
};

var canvas = _createCanvas();

setCanvasAndLoadImage("https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2014/02/01/17/30/apple-256267_960_720.jpg", canvas, _drawAndProcessImage);
```

```html
<p id="log"></p>
```

Comment: @harristyle did you try it?

Comment: this is probably what's wrong, but I've looked into the link you gave and also some other websites and i can't seem to work out a solution for it, is a server 100% necessary for this kind of thing, or can i somehow get away with doing this by browser side only? I've tried setting the img.crossOrigin to 'anonymous' but that alone doesn't seem to solve it.

Comment: @harristyle it doesn't solve it by alone as you see. you need a proxy server like cloudinary or something that would send you valid cors http header tags or you would do that by hand. or you would store the images in the same server that's running js.

Comment: i see. well, thnx for the help, i guess i'll try to find other ways around it, or maybe i'll implement a server. anyways ill accept your answer for now.

Comment: @harristyle i've already implemented a proxy server. i can send it to you if you want to try.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is stems from the lines

```
canvas.width = img.naturalWidth;
canvas.height = img.naturalHeight;
```

You are asking for the image dimensions but the image has not been loaded. You have to move that to the image's `onload` event.

Comment: I tried this now but the outcome remains the same. also, ive tried assigning some arbitrary number to the width and height before the onload and the outcome is still the same. (ive tried canvas.width = 1000; canvas.height = 1000;)

Comment: Are you sure? If I do `canvas.width = 1000; canvas.height = 1000;` it seems to work.

Comment: @harristyle did you try my solution? also, i've talked about some cors mechanisms. that's why you weren't getting the correct data.